# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined - requireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have a few libraries that use `jQuery` instead of `$`. I'm using requireJS to load all my javascript, I'e encountered the error message in the title. How can I tell requireJS to allow jQuery to be available under the alias `jQuery` as well as `$`?

#### app.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        app: '../app',

        "jquery": "lib/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min",
        "jqueryui": "lib/jquery-ui.min",
        "easyloader": "lib/easyui/easyloader",
        'domReady': 'lib/domReady'

    },

    shim: {
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'bootstrap'], function($) {

});
```

Comment: Defining dependencies with shim should be enough (the same way as you currently have for bootstrap which depends on jquery).

Comment: Libraries which use jQuery will use jQuery from global namespace. You only have to define dependency using shim config.

Comment: Yep this basically solved my problem I added this line to the shim config: `'bootstrap-wizard': ['jquery']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a dependency to the shim configuration solves this.

`'bootstrap-wizard': ['jquery']`